# Getting the template name in django template

Tags: python, django

For debugging purposes, I would like to have a variable in all my templates holding the path of the template being rendered.  For example, if a view renders templates/account/logout.html I would like {{ template_name }} to contain the string templates/account/logout.html.

I don't want to go and change any views (specially because I'm reusing a lot of apps), so the way to go seems to be a context processor that introspects something. The question is what to introspect.

Or maybe this is built in and I don't know about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The easy way:**

Download and use the [django debug toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/tree/master).  You'll get an approximation of what you're after and a bunch more.

**The less easy way:**

Replace `Template.render` with `django.test.utils.instrumented_test_render`, listen for the `django.test.signals.template_rendered` signal, and add the name of the template to the context.  Note that `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` must be true in your settings file or there will be no origin from which to get the name.

```
if settings.DEBUG and settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG

    from django.test.utils import instrumented_test_render
    from django.test.signals import template_rendered


    def add_template_name_to_context(self, sender, **kwargs)
        template = kwargs['template']
        if template.origin and template.origin.name
            kwargs['context']['template_name'] = template.origin.name

    Template.render = instrumented_test_render

    template_rendered.connect(add_template_name_to_context)
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Django 1.5 release notes](https://django-doc-test1.readthedocs.io/en/stable-1.5.x/releases/1.5.html#new-view-variable-in-class-based-views-context):

> **New view variable in class-based views context**
>
> In all generic class-based views (or any class-based view inheriting from `ContextMixin`), the context dictionary contains a `view` variable that points to the `View` instance.

Therefore, if you're using class-based views, you can use

```
{{ view.template_name }}
```

This works if `template_name` is explicitly set as an attribute on the view.

Otherwise, you can use

```
{{ view.get_template_names }}
```

to get a list of templates, e.g. `['catalog/book_detail.html']`.

Answer (score 2):

Templates are just strings not file names.  Probably your best option is to monkey patch `render_to_response` and/or `direct_to_template` and copy the filename arg into the context.