# Get template name in template tag ( Django )

Tags: python, django, django-templates

is there a way to get the template name ( being parsed ) in a template tag ?
I have read searched and found nothing, only this previous post 
[Getting the template name in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859319/getting-the-template-name-in-django-template)

which doesn't help me much, since the answer relies on settings.DEBUG being true, which in my case can't be.

I don't really know where to start on this one, so any suggestion is welcome :)

***EDIT***

So basically what i want is to create a plugable tag that when rendered it checks for a Tag object, this would be the source for the tag object

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    template = models.CharFIeld(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    plugins = models.ForeignKey(PluginBase)
```

if theres a tag object, then it displays all plugin objects, if not it creates a tag object unique to the name provided in the template tag and the template name, if getting the template name is not possible, then i guess i can just make it unique per name. The whole tag is kinda like a placeholder, for those familiar with django-cms

Comment: I suspect, that this is not possible. As far as I know the template structure gets parsed into a tree like model before the interpretation of the tags is done. So I would assume the information needed by you is lost when the templatetag gets executed. (This is only a wild guess but I think you should plan an alternative way ;) )

Comment: What's your actual use case? I suspect there's better ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps do this with a context processor, but I'm not sure if these have access to the name of the template.

What will work is to make a wrapper for the rendering calls you do. Say you currently do the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', { 'foo': 'bar', })
```

If you create your own wrapper for this, you could add the template name to the dictionary before the actual render takes place:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def myrender(request, template, dictionary):
    dictionary.update({'template_name': template})
    return render(request, template, dictionary)
```

Then in your views, change it as follows (assuming you saved the above function in `myutils.py`, and it is available on your path):

```
#from django.shortcuts import render <- delete this line
from myutils import myrender as render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', { 'foo': 'bar', })
```

Now all your `render` calls will update the dictionary with the template name. In any template, then just use `{{ template_name }}` to get the name. You can of course also update other rendering function like `render_to_response` and such in a similar fashion.

Also, the `import myrender as render` might or might not confuse you later on because it is named like the Django function... if so, just import it without the "`as render`", and replace all `render` calls with `myrender`. Personally I'd prefer this since this makes it a drop-in replacement for the existing rendering functions.

Comment: thanks, but this since its a template tag that needs access, i don't really use a view rendering function, because basically i want the template tag to get its template name and do some processing with it. I do agree on a context processor but don't really know how to get my hands on the name :(

Comment: How are you using the template if you don't render it?

Comment: i meant i won't be the one rendering the template through a view since it was meant to be open source

Comment: I can't really think of a way to do that without modifying at least some python code: be it the views themselves, or the Django source as Shawn mentioned in his answer. Guess it boils down to do the one that has the least impact on your target audience...?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source, while the [`Template`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/base.py?rev=17133#L115) object would have access to the template name (via `.name`) this value is never passed on to the [Parser](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/base.py?rev=17133#L230) object and therefore not available to template tags.

There are various ways of making the template name available to the template itself (by adding it to the context) but not within the template tags.

As Daniel Roseman mentioned in the comments, if you can elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve, there may be a better way to achieve what you want. No offence, but this sounds like it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/134327).

---

Out of academic interest, I had a quick fiddle to see if it was possible. As far as I can see, it is possible but not without changing or monkey patching the django source.

*Note: the following is **not  a recommended solution** and merely hints at what may be required to actually make this work. Not to be used for production code.*

By modifying `django.template.base.py` with the following changes, we add the `.template_name` attribute to the parser object making it available to template tags.

1. [Added optional arg to `compile_string`](https://gist.github.com/1388704#L144)
2. [Added template name as extra attribute to parser](https://gist.github.com/1388704#L153)
3. [Passed in the template name when calling `compile_string()`](https://gist.github.com/1388704#L125)

To test this out, I defined the following tag which simply returns the template name in caps:

```
from django.template.base import Node, Library
register = Library()

class TemplateNameNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, template_name):
        self.name = template_name

    def render(self, context):
        return self.name.upper()

@register.tag
def caps_template_name(parser, token):
     return TemplateNameNode(parser.template_name)
```

and the following template:

```
{% load mytags %}
Template name in caps: {% caps_template_name %}
```

This seems to work when tested in `./manage.py shell`:

```
>>> from django.template import loader, Context
>>> t = loader.get_template("test.html")
>>> t.render(Context({}))
u'\nTemplate name in caps: TEST.HTML\n'
```

While this seems to work, I should reiterate that manually patching the django source **never a good solution** and is subject to all sorts of misery when migrating to different versions.