# send user back to where he came from in django.

Tags: django, templates, view

Can I find out the template that requested this request and render that template in a view?

Suppose `A.html` POSTed to foo_view, then I want to `return render(request, 'A.html')`
if `B.html` POSTed to foo_view, then I wan to `return render(request, 'B.html')`

possible?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859319/getting-the-template-name-in-django-template

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to check the `Referer` header, but that's not reliable since it's up to the client to decide whether to send it or not.

Since you mention `POST` perhaps the easiest thing to do is include a hidden input on the page that gives the name of the template. You can then check the value of this input in the view receiving the `POST`.